# How does historical linguistics reconstruct languages that have no written record?

Tags: historical-linguistics

How are ancient languages like PIE (proto-Indo-European) known?

Comment: A good book to read that explains everything about this topic very well and is also readable is Larry Trask's _Historical Linguistics_. Look for a used copy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The basic method of reconstruction has two parts. First, you have to assemble language data into a table, where each column is a particular language and each row is a word, holding form and meaning as constant a possible. For example you can make a table of words for "mother" and "father" across Indo-European languages – to be disciplined and constrained, just look at Old Norse, Latin, Greek, Sanskrit, and Old Church Slavic. Then you compare and extract regularities. You will notice that the word for "mother" begins with [m] in all of these languages, so we make the reasonable conjecture that the PIE (reconstructed) word also begins with [m]. You also notice that the word for "father" begins with [p] in Greek, Latin, Sanskrit, and [f] in Old Norse – also, the OCS word seems to be totally different. We hypothesize that the PIE word begins with [p], bearing in mind that it might be something else. We also add the Old Norse word fjǫðr "feather", Greek *pteron*, Latin *penna* which reinforces this relation, that *p* in Greek and Latin corresponds to *f* in Germanic.

The premise is that one can posit sounds of the proto-language which map regularly to sounds of daughter languages, whereby it is a (mostly) reliable rule that Germanic *f* comes from PIE *p*, and furthermore Germanic *p* comes from PIE *b*. Certain sounds are more challenging, for example PIE *bh* becomes *ph* in Greek, *b* in Slavic (same as PIE *b*), *bh* in Sanskrit but *b* in Old Iranian (same as PIE *b*). We partition the *bh* words separate from the *b* words, then use various kinds of reasoning to see that the *b* words mostly have *b* as their daughter reflex, but the *bh* words – which have something that isn't the same as *b* – generally have some voiced oral labial that isn't *b*, and is actually *bh* in Sanskrit. Thus we take the leap that it must have been *bh*. No language directly attests *gʷh*, but we can see by analogy that there was such a sound that isn't *gʷ* but is like *gʷ* in certain ways, and is also like *gh* in certain ways. That is (very roughly) how we reason to specific phonetic values. The premise that sounds change according to rules (as opposed to random mutations) guides the sorting of observed words into correspondence sets.

Comment: Very like a sudoku.